# Django related manager of abstract class

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, abstract

I want to iterate over all my ConnectorModels instances.

```
class ClientModel(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ConnectorModel(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(ClientModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class TelegramModel(ConnectorModel):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class URLModel(ConnectorModel):
    phone = models.UR(max_length=20)
```

When I now get an instantiated version of my ClientModel, I expected to get a connectermodel_set attribute, however I got a TelegramModel_set and an URLModel_set.

How do I get connectormodel_set?

EDIT:

connectormodel_set should return the union of all related telegram and url models

Comment: maybe https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/ could help you

Answer (score 1):

You can't have that with an abstract model. A ForeignKey needs to point to an ID in an actual table, and an abstract model does not represent a table.

There are two options for achieving what you want. The first is to use a concrete base model - which has the disadvantage of an extra database join each time to get the extended data. The second is to use [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) rather than a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `ConnectorModel` is abstract model, not real one. It's only for make other models - `TelegramModel` and `URLModel` for your situation.

If you want to call `ConnectorModel`, please remove abstract from `ConnectorModel`. And just make other abstract model for others, or just make telegram and url fields to connectormodel. like below.

```
class ClientModel(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ConnectorModel(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(ClientModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    telegram_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    url_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # remove abstract
    # class Meta:
    #   abstract = True

# add models with client ForeignKey 
class TelegramModel(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(ClientModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class URLModel(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(ClientModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.UR(max_length=20)
```